# Subspace of the product space $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the Munkres and found a theorem (namely, the Theorem 19.3) and I didn't get it:

> **Theorem 19.3**  Let $A_{\alpha}$ be a subspace of $X_{\alpha}$ , for each $\alpha \in J$. Then $\prod A_{\alpha}$ is a subspace of $\prod X_{\alpha}$ if both products are given the box topology, or if both products are given the product topology.

How one shows that a given set is a subspace of other one? I think this is what I don't get in this theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must show that $U$ is an open subset of $\prod A_\alpha,$ if and only if there is some open subset $V$ of $\prod X_\alpha$ such that $U=V\cap\prod A_\alpha$ (meaning $U$ is open in the subspace topology on $\prod A_\alpha$ induced by $\prod X_\alpha$). Do you know the definitions of the box and product topologies?

Comment: I do, but I don't get why I have to show that the open sets of $\prod A_{\alpha}$ are of that form.

Comment: That's from definition of subspace topology. Let $Y ⊆ X$ each having its own topology. Then $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ iff its open sets are exactly $Y ∩ V$ for $V$ open in $X$.

Comment: @JuanPablo: Let's put $A=\prod A_\alpha$ and $X=\prod X_\alpha.$ Say $A$ and $X$ are given the box topology. We need to show that if $U$ is $A$-open, then $U=A\cap V$ for some $X$-open $V$. This shows that the subspace topology on $A$ induced by $X$ is *finer* than the box topology on $A$. We also need to show that if $V$ is $X$-open, then $A\cap V$ is $A$-open. This shows that the subspace topology on $A$ induced by $X$ is *coarser* than the box topology on $A$. Hence, the box topology on $A$ *is* the subspace topology induced by $X$. Likewise when $A$ and $X$ are given the product topology.

Comment: The definition of subspace topology is going to be *essential* to this proof, since it shows up in the hypotheses *and* the conclusions. You should make sure you understand it before proceeding.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks C:

Comment: @JuanPablo Excellent! Glad I could get you unstuck.